# Constructing a particular sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to construct a sequence whose the initial term is a positive constant $a>1$, and the following terms progressively tends to 1.

I'm looking for something which decreases slowly. In particular, for the first 40 terms, their values have to stay between $a-1$ and $a$.

What kind of sequence can do that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What about $a_n=a^{1/n}$?

Comment: Thanks for your proposition Richard. I'm looking for something which decreases slowly.

Comment: You could slow it down, I guess.  Variations on this would work, say, $a^{1/(1+\log(n))}$.

Comment: Does the sequence have to be infinite? If not just reduce by $10^{-6}$ or whatever at each step. Or take $1+\frac{a-1}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Almagest : Thanks for your suggestion but I don't understand your question.

Comment: I would like something where for the first 40 terms, their values stay between $a-1$ and $a$. I've updated my post.

Comment: In infinite series the first finitely many terms are never interested, what you need to worry about is its asymptotic when $n\rightarrow \infty$. So first you should ask yourself what it should be.  Otherwise sequence  $a_n=a-\frac{1}{40}$ for $n=1,\ldots,40$ and $a_n=a^{\frac{1}{n-39}}$ for $n>40$, clearly satisfies your condition but I doubt it is useful.

Answer (score 3):

How about $a_n$ = $a_0^{1/n}$, $a_0$ >0

Comment: Thanks dalia. It was the proposition from Richard.

Comment: I want something which decreases more slowly. I've updated my post.